# (RestAssured) Extract nested path as given type

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Let's say I have following model:

```
@Data
class Model {
    private String someField;
    private String otherField;
}
```

And following JSON response in RestAssured:

```
{
     wrapperField: {
          someField: "some value",
          otherField: "other value"
     }
}
```

Is it possible to use `extract().as()` construction in the nested path?

Something like:

```
getService().get("my-endpoint").then().extract("wrapperField").as(Model.class)
```

Comment: isn't this the right syntax to deserialize? `Model model = get("/wrapperField").as(Model.class)`

Comment: It doesn't matter for me if I will use `extract` or not. I want to map nested part of the response, to the model.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something less elegant? Like that:

```
Response r = given()
            .when()
            .get(url)
            .then()
            .extract()
            .response();

r.getBody().jsonPath().getObject("path", Model.class);
```

Comment: You can call `jsonPath()` right after `extract()`: `.then().extract().jsonPath().getObject("path", Model.class)`